# Add array to all nodes in query - Firebase JS

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I got and structure like that:

```
{'-LH88EMN8Q0Mh5ZxbXyx':{
  u_id: 101,
  g_id: 6064,
  members:[101, 102]
  last_msg:'testing'
},
 '-eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLC':{
  u_id: 102,
  g_id: 6065,
  members:[101, 102],
  last_msg:'testing'
},
etc
}
```

I´m using a query to recover every item with group id; but i need to add to every interaction in query an array with de current user_id. Something like:

`firebase.database().ref('msgs').orderByChild('g_id').equalTo(gID)
    .update({ dBy: [user_id] });`

But not recognice that function; or nothing happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Realtime Database can only write data if it knows the exact location to write to. It doesn't support something like update queries that you may know from SQL.

This means that you'll need to attach a listener to the query, and update each individual result from there.

It'll look something like this:

```
firebase.database().ref('msgs').orderByChild('g_id').equalTo(gID)
    once("value", function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
            child.ref.update({ dBy: [user_id] });
        });
    });
```